# copy-Paste a range data as many time as there are headers name starting with "X"

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to find a solution for that problem but nothing came up.

Here is the problem I've got. I would like to copy a variable data range from a sheet called ("Amounts") starting in range "C3" to an other sheet called ("Pasted Amounts") in range F2 as many time as columns, in sheets "Amounts" are starting with the following value " Amounts in USD".

I've been coding something but it doesn't work... I put a counter in a cell to count how many time there are columns starting with the value " Amounts in USD" in order to pick the value  appearing in that cell and repeat the paste process. But I've been complicated the code I guess...

Here is my code;

```
Dim cel2 As Range
Dim counter as Integer

With Sheets("Amounts")
Worksheets("Amounts").Activate
      For Each cel2 In Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight))
         If cel2.Value Like "Amount in USD*" Then
                counter = counter + 1
                Range("U4").Value = counter
          End If
                
          With Worksheets("Pasted Amounts").Activate
            '~Here is bellow the column named " clients name" I want to paste in "Pasted amounts" sheet (by coping it in the sheet "Amounts"
             worksheets("Amounts").Range("C3",range("C3").end(xldown).Select
            '~ Paste the range copied in sheet " Pasted Amount" as many time the counter value is
             .Copy Range("F2").Resize(.Count * counter) 
          End With
     Next cel2

End With

End sub
```

Once again, I'd appreciate so much your help...

Mido88

Comment: You could replace the first if with `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A2", Range("A2").End(xlToRight)), "Amount in USD*")` And you don't need to activate the sheet when using `with` but you need to put `.Range` otherwise it will refer to activesheet.

Comment: Thank you Christofer for your answer. 
I tried to put the code you adivced me but It didnt word. The line turned red + i got a compile error message that says ":= is awaited". Do you know why ?

Comment: I'm trying to make sense of the last part. Where are you copying to and from what?

Comment: Anything [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215864/copy-all-data-from-column-based-on-condition)?

Comment: Ok,  I want to copy from a worksheet called ("Amounts")  to the worksheet called "Pasted Amount" in the cell "F2". 
And on the sheet called "Amounts" there are columns which headers start with "Amounts in USD"+ other words. The point is that I want Excel to automatically count how many time Amounts in USD appear in each column header in order to copy an other  specific column named " Client names" existing in this sheet to an other sheet called " Pasted Amounts" in range("F2"). That's it.
Is it more clear to you ? I can re explain if needed :)

Comment: @Naresh 
Yes somehow, however I want to copy a specific column in a 2nd sheet as many time as there are column's header starting with "Amounts in USD" in the first sheet.

Comment: Isn't this similar to your last question? Simply adapt that code to work on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I found the solution!
Thank you again Siddharth and Christofer, your answers helped me a lot to think further...
Here is the solution that worked really well! I used the answer in the previous post I made here:[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68215864/copy-all-data-from-column-based-on-condition) and added a single line code to paste as many time the range of datas as" Amounts in USD " was found in the previous sheet.

Sorry again for those misunderstandings. I hope that my answer would help you and the other users in need!
Here it is;

```
Sub Sample()
   Dim wsInput As Worksheet
   Dim wsOutput As Worksheet
   Dim lRowInput As Long
   Dim lRowOutput As Long
   Dim lCol As Long
   Dim i As Long
   Dim Col As String
   
   '~~> Set your sheets here
   Set wsInput = Sheets("Amounts")
   Set wsOutput = Sheets("Pasted Amounts")
   
   With wsInput
       '~~> Find last column in Row 2
       lCol = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       
       '~~> Loop through columns
       For i = 1 To lCol
           '~~> Check for your criteria
           If .Cells(2, i).Value2 Like "Amount in functional currency*" Then
               '~~> Get column name
               Col = Split(.Cells(, i).Address, "$")(1)
               
               '~~> Get the last row in that column
               lRowInput = .Range(Col & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
               
               '~~> Find the next row to write to
               If lRowOutput = 0 Then
                   lRowOutput = 2
               Else
                   lRowOutput = wsOutput.Range("A" & wsOutput.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               End If
               
               '~~> Copy the datas ( for each column where Amounts in USD was found)
               .Range(Col & "3:" & Col & lRowInput).Copy _
               wsOutput.Range("A" & lRowOutput)

               ~~> SOLUTION BELLOW-Copy the variable data range ("C3") 
                Worksheets("Amounts").Activate
               .Range("C3", Range("C3").End(xlDown)).Copy wsOutput.Range("F" & lRowOutput)
           End If
       Next i
   End With
End Sub
```

Mido

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
Dim LastColumn As Long, LastRow As Long, counter as Long
With Sheets("Amounts")
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    counter = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A1", .Cells(1, LastColumn)), "Amount in USD*")
    .Range("C3:C" & LastRow).Copy _
    Worksheets("Pasted Amounts").Range("F2").Resize(.Range("C3:C" & LastRow).Count * counter)
End With
End Sub
```

Or as a silly long one line of code:

```
Sub test()
Sheets("Amounts").Range("C3:C" & Sheets("Amounts").Cells(Sheets("Amounts").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Copy Worksheets("Pasted Amounts").Range("F2").Resize(Sheets("Amounts").Range("C3:C" & Sheets("Amounts").Cells(Sheets("Amounts").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row).Count * WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Amounts").Range("A1", Sheets("Amounts").Cells(1, Sheets("Amounts").Cells(1, Sheets("Amounts").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)), "Amount in USD*"))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Christofer unfortunately that is not what  I was expecting.
Sorry for my bad english though.
I refreshed the post and I did some modifications in the posted code too. It should be more understandable. If still not tell me haha

Comment: @Mido88 Do you want to copy the entirety of C3:Cx To F2:Fx? And then do it again for each of the counter? Like C3:C4 to F2:F6 if the counter is 2? OR  do you want to copy as much of C3:Cx as the counter is, so C3:C6 to F2:F5 if the counter is 3?

Comment: "Do you want to copy the entirety of C3:Cx To F2:Fx? And then do it again for each of the counter? Like C3:C4 to F2:F6 if the counter is 2?"==> YES !! that's what I want! :)

Comment: @Mido88 What about this then? And if not, what's not working properly?